# Collections.unmodifiableList not working for list.addAll()

Tags: java

I'm doing some research on `Collection (List, Set)` where I am trying to modify the contents of `List` interface though I used `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`. So below is what I developed

```
public class CollectionDemo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> modifiable = new ArrayList<>();
        modifiable.add("Java");
        modifiable.add("Spring");
        modifiable = Collections.unmodifiableList(modifiable);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Oracle");
        list.add("MySQL");
        list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        finalList.addAll(modifiable);
        finalList.addAll(list);
        finalList.add("Python");

        // Now remove value from list object
        finalList.remove("Oracle");

        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}
Output (O/P): [Java, Spring, MySQL, Python]
```

Here I used `Collections.unmodifiableList` on both list objects to allow not to modify list (which works fine independently), but when created one more list and adding these two list objects, it allows me to `remove` previous list contents, which I wanted to not allow in my project implementation? Do anyone know how / why it's happening?

Comment: But you aren't using the list (writes) returned by `unmodifiableList`.

Comment: `finalList` is not unmodifiable... what did you expect and why?

Comment: *"Collection (List, Set and Map)"* ... I hope you do not think that `Map` extends the `Collection` interface.

Comment: `List.addAll` only adds the *contents* of the other list. I think that's the source of confusion here.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I think its adding content to other list and we can operate on it.  Thanks, Hema

Comment: @Tom : nitpicking. `java.util.Map` does not extend `java.util.Collection`, but generically speaking, a map is a type of collection.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Since there is an interface with the name `Collection` I would be very careful with my choice of words (if other like to mix stuff around, then it is their choice).

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying `finalList`, which is not unmodifiable, and therefore can be modified. The two unmodifiable lists (`modifiable` and `list`) remain unchanged when you add/remove element to/from `finalList`.